# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las clases de todos los < li > usando el DOM en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Se que parece obvio pero he probado con todas las opciones (selectQueryAll hasta selectByTagName) y no me funciona. Sólo logro seleccionar el primer < li > con selectElementById. Si pruebo con otros entonces no funciona ninguno.

He aquí mi código y lo que trato de hacer es simplemente cuando se le da click a un < li > de mi navbar, que haga efecto 3d de "zoomOutDown" de la galería "animate.css". Con esto lo logro pero sólo con el primero:

```html
 <nav>
        <div class="logoName">Javier Cake</div>
        <div class="ulDiv">
            <ul>
                <li id="probando" class="vacio" href=""><a>Home</a></li>
                <li id="probando" class="vacio" href=""><a>About</a></li>
                <li id="probando" class="vacio" href=""><a>Skills</a></li>
                <li id="probando" class="vacio" href=""><a>Work</a></li>
                <li id="probando" class="vacio" href=""><a>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("probando");

function botonabajo(){
    boton.className = "animated zoomOutDown";
}

boton.addEventListener("click", botonabajo);
```

Me di cuenta que claro sólo estaba seleccionando el primer id "probando" que se encuentra. Entonces he probado con "querySelectorAll(#probando)" o "querySelectorAll("li")" o "selectElementsbyTag("li") o etc pero entonces no me selecciona ninguno. ¿Alguien me puede decir que me está faltando?

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es lanzar una acción cada vez que se hace clic en cualquiera de los `li`?

Comment: Si, cada vez que se le da click al < li >, se le aplica automaticamente la clase "zoomOutDown" al < li >, y eso hace que haga un efecto estético.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás confundiendo los IDs con las clases.

Un **ID** es un identificador **ÚNICO** mientras que una **clase** se utiliza para agrupar elementos **COMUNES** a todos los elementos que la usan.

Por lo tanto, como no quieres referenciar solo a un elemento, deberías obtener todos los `<li>` a través de su clase común e iterar mediante un bucle sobre cada uno de ellos. De esta manera, podrás asignarle la función a cada uno de ellos independientemente. Para ello, he usado el método `getElementsByClassName` que te devuelve un array de elementos con todos los elementos que usen esa clase.

También fíjate en que he utilizado la palabra reservada `this` la cual permite hacer referencia al objeto (en este caso cada uno de los `<li>`) al que estamos haciendo clic en cada momento.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("vacio");

function botonabajo(){
    this.className = "animated zoomOutDown";
}

for(var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++)
{
   botones.item(i).addEventListener("click", botonabajo);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logoName">Javier Cake</div>
  <div class="ulDiv">
      <ul>
          <li id="probando1" class="vacio" href=""><a>Home</a></li>
          <li id="probando2" class="vacio" href=""><a>About</a></li>
          <li id="probando3" class="vacio" href=""><a>Skills</a></li>
          <li id="probando4" class="vacio" href=""><a>Work</a></li>
          <li id="probando5" class="vacio" href=""><a>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Gracias. Como sabe el programa simplemente con la palabra "this" que te refieres a los botones?  Por qué no se puede poner simplemente "botones.ClassName"?

Comment: @JavierCake `botones` es el conjunto de todos los elementos del array por lo que no le podrías asignar directamente un className. La palabra reservada `this` es una palabra reservada que se puede utilizar en una gran cantidad de contextos, ambientes y formas diferentes. En este caso, al ser una palabra reservada de Javascript, el propio Javascript detecta en cada momento al elemento con el que estás interactuando, por lo que lo podemos utilizar para asignar la clase al `<li>` al que estemos haciendo clic en cada momento y de esta manera, nos facilita las cosas a la hora de referenciarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes alcanzar todos los `li` simplemente con `querySelectorAll('li')` y luego aplicas un `click` listener a cada uno en el cual le agregues la clase `animated zoomOutDown`, la forma de hacerlo dependerá de si quieres sólo agregar esa clase a lo que ya hay o sustituir la clase que tiene por esta nueva, etc.

Otra cosa, evita dar el mismo `id` a más de un elemento en tu DOM, eso es incorrecto.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.className = 'animated zoomOutDown';
    console.log(this.className);
  });
});
```

```css
.animated,
.zoomOutDown {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logoName">Javier Cake</div>
  <div class="ulDiv">
    <ul>
      <li id="probando1" class="vacio" href=""><a>Home</a></li>
      <li id="probando2" class="vacio" href=""><a>About</a></li>
      <li id="probando3" class="vacio" href=""><a>Skills</a></li>
      <li id="probando4" class="vacio" href=""><a>Work</a></li>
      <li id="probando5" class="vacio" href=""><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```